# How to get data label on bar chart using chartjs with Ng2Chart

Tags: angular, chart.js, ng2-charts

I have Angular project in which i have implemented bar chart using [chartjs](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/charts/bar.html). Also get same behaviour as define in document but my requirement is to display value of it on bar like below:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OBwkA.png)

### bar.component.html

```
<div fxLayout="row">
    <canvas class="{{classDefination}}" id="{{id}}"></canvas>
</div>
```

### bar.component.ts

```
public chart: any;
  @Input() id: string = "";
  @Input() values: number[] = [53, 31, 22, 18, 14];
  // @Input() values: number[] = [];
  @Input() labels: string[] = ["Nokia Pte. Ltd.", "Apple Pte. Ltd.", "Samsung Pte. Ltd.", "Alphabet Pte. Ltd.", "Xiaomi Pte. Ltd."];
  // @Input() labels: string[] = [];
  @Input() backgroundColors: string[] = ["#25C8B4", "#5BFFE1", "#7AEFDA", "#ADFFF5", "#CCFFE7"];
  // @Input() backgroundColors: string[] = [];
  @Input() classDefination: string = "";
  @Input() barTitleLable: boolean = false;
  @Input() barTooltipEnable: boolean = true;
  @Input() displayDetailOfData: boolean = true;
  @Input() barBaseAxis: any = "x"; // Always type String. if 'x' or 'y'
  @Input() barThickness: number = 50;
  xAxisLableVisiable: boolean = false;
  yAxisLableVisiable: boolean = false;
```

```
 constructor(private ref: ChangeDetectorRef) { }
```

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    if (this.barBaseAxis && this.barBaseAxis == 'y') {
      this.yAxisLableVisiable = true;
    } else {
      this.xAxisLableVisiable = true;
    }
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.createChart();
    }, 0);
    this.ref.detectChanges();
  }

  createChart() {
    this.chart = new Chart(this.id, {
      type: 'bar',
      data: {
        labels: this.labels,
        datasets: [
          {
            data: this.values,
            backgroundColor: this.backgroundColors,
            hoverBackgroundColor: this.backgroundColors,
            hoverBorderColor: this.backgroundColors,
            barThickness: this.barThickness,

          }
        ]
      },
      options: {
        responsive: true,
        indexAxis: this.barBaseAxis, // Base Axis.  
        scales: {
          x: {
            grid: { //Hide background lines.
              display: false,
              drawBorder: this.xAxisLableVisiable
            },
            ticks: { // For hide Lables on Y-axis.
              display: this.xAxisLableVisiable
            }
          },
          y: {
            grid: {
              display: false,
              drawBorder: this.xAxisLableVisiable
            },
            ticks: { // For hide Lables on Y-axis.
              display: this.yAxisLableVisiable
            },
          }
        },
        plugins: {
          legend: { // Hide top lables.
            display: this.barTitleLable
          },
          tooltip: { // Hover tooltip
            enabled: this.barTooltipEnable
          },

        }
      }
    });
  }
```

Expecting result is chart with data label into each bar.

Comment: I think you should use datalabels plugin. In NG2chart, there is a sample similar to your need: https://valor-software.com/ng2-charts/#BarChart